# MVC - Custom Validation - Error Message stays until page is submitted again

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, client-side-validation

I created a MVC custom validator with Client side validation. 
when user submits the view; custom validation is checked and if it returns false; error message is displayed on the view. 
Then user goes to that field and fixes the problem. Issue is that; the error message stays there until user submits the page again. This is not the behavior I want.

Default MVC validators (requires, range etc) error messages are hidden as soon the the error is fixed, how do I achieve that in Jquery? Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes, first you should put your message in span. give span an id and after fixing error call function that checks if error has been fixed or not if yes hide that error span id.
If you are validating in textbox you can call validation function on onkeyup.

Comment: I though about that; user fixes issue; I hide the span user makes another mistake, then the new error message can not be shown but page cant be submitted neither, is there a way to clean that message without hiding the whole div/span?

Comment: yes, use jqury empty(). which will empty the content of span